# ios upload/download file from desktop

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need my ios device to act like a server i.e. once I connect my iphone with computer I'll be able to upload documents to iphone and as well as download documents from iphone. I know this is possible but I forgot library that allow us to do that. Does anybody knows such library? Also any sample code will be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AsyncSocket.
Using socket connection you can make your iphone as a server by running your app which makes a socket connection.

Comment: Is it possible that I trasnfer data via usb cable connecting computer and iphone i.e. iphone act like a server and computer act like a client

Comment: @AyazAlavi: You can perform any action similar to a server-client over a network.A simple data transfer via data cable is not possible.Since the the app which is running is make the iphone as a server.can perform any transfer over the network.